# Montserrat font styles does not work , why?

Tags: html, css, google-fonts

I have embedded all of the google monsterrat font styles and put it inside my html file , but It does not work , I have tried the thin on e, black one , italic ones nothing happened ,  last thing how can I add code snippet ? .
Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>

      <style>
                h1 {
                          font-family: 'Montserrat-Black';
                }

                p {
                          font-family: 'Montserrat-Thin';
                }
      </style>


      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap"
                rel="stylesheet">

      </head>

      <body>


      <h1 style="margin-left: 500px;">
                This is my H1 Tag
      </h1>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et dolore obcaecati mollitia laborum tempora
                quisquam? Quae quam aliquid nesciunt laborum est saepe facere corporis, impedit amet enim, magnam
                dolores provident?
                Obcaecati, dolores laborum, quidem nemo a molestiae totam perspiciatis asperiores, deserunt
                perferendis quis ad. Explicabo molestiae culpa dolores! Architecto id maxime impedit iusto
                distinctio quasi voluptatibus blanditiis, molestiae nam asperiores!
                Mollitia facere, eaque ipsum, quia asperiores possimus esse culpa omnis consequuntur soluta adipisci
                aspernatur dolor unde natus officia atque dicta eum, et doloribus voluptatem debitis amet! Omnis
                beatae magni qui?
                Accusantium pariatur deleniti dicta reiciendis velit, eius eveniet optio at nulla dolore neque
                quaerat quae tempore non quibusdam ipsam dolorum error animi odio molestiae enim aliquid
                exercitationem officia! Enim, saepe.</p>

      </body>

      </html>
```

anyone knows the problem ?
Thanks with regards .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adjust the weight of the font you need to use the `font-weight` property:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 900;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>
  This is my H1 Tag
</h1>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et dolore obcaecati mollitia laborum tempora
  quisquam? Quae quam aliquid nesciunt laborum est saepe facere corporis, impedit amet enim, magnam
  dolores provident?
  Obcaecati, dolores laborum, quidem nemo a molestiae totam perspiciatis asperiores, deserunt
  perferendis quis ad. Explicabo molestiae culpa dolores! Architecto id maxime impedit iusto
  distinctio quasi voluptatibus blanditiis, molestiae nam asperiores!
  Mollitia facere, eaque ipsum, quia asperiores possimus esse culpa omnis consequuntur soluta adipisci
  aspernatur dolor unde natus officia atque dicta eum, et doloribus voluptatem debitis amet! Omnis
  beatae magni qui?
  Accusantium pariatur deleniti dicta reiciendis velit, eius eveniet optio at nulla dolore neque
  quaerat quae tempore non quibusdam ipsam dolorum error animi odio molestiae enim aliquid
  exercitationem officia! Enim, saepe.
</p>
```

Comment: So this is the only way by font-weight , there is no other ways to give it inside the font-family ?

Comment: Cause I have seen a video on this that was just writing font-family :  "montserrat-black";

Comment: @TwanaStackoverflow It depends on how the font is packaged and served. It's possible to break a font like `Montserrat` apart into different fonts with different weights, e.g. `Montserrat-Thin` and `Montserrat-Black`, but I don't know if Google Fonts does this, or if it did so in the past. Regardless, the recommended modern approach is always to use `font-weight` since it's more semantic.

Comment: Thanks brother , appreciated ❤